# Socket.io messages not received in chrome

Tags: google-chrome, socket.io

I am working on a socket.io implementation of room based chat system. The web app works perfectly in Firefox, however, in Chrome, only one way communication is achieved. That is, the client in Chrome mobile version, doesn't receive the updates emitted from other devices, but is able to emit messages to other devices. Also, please note that things work perfectly, when tried in Firefox Mobile, Firefox Desktop or Chrome Desktop.

Some other answers suggest that this may be a version issue but all the modules are upto date.

Is it a common issue? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

For others facing similar issue :
Switching off "Data Saver" in chrome mobile solved the problem for me!